# ADF mobile : can't deploye apps in device

Tags: oracle-adf

When i deploy app in device.  I got following error. I used xcode 4.6.

```
[03:43:57 PM] Command-line executed:  /usr/bin/xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication -v /Users/evosys/jdeveloper/mywork/ConsumeWS/deploy/distribute/Destination_Root/Applications/ConsumeWS.app -o /Users/evosys/jdeveloper/mywork/ConsumeWS/deploy/distribute/Destination_Root/Oracle_ADFmc_Container_Application/device/ConsumeWS.ipa --sign iPhone Developer: Rakesh Raman (G445TJT9SV) --embed /Users/evosys/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/827FDDF6-210D-4725-9018-B2C6FC222FD4.mobileprovision
[03:44:00 PM] error: /usr/bin/codesign --force --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements,resource-rules --sign iPhone Developer: Rakesh Raman (G445TJT9SV) --resource-rules=/var/folders/6w/ycncqpg12mj_l56xbqgly6_80000gn/T/ZSzoPT55UE/Payload/ConsumeWS.app/ResourceRules.plist /var/folders/6w/ycncqpg12mj_l56xbqgly6_80000gn/T/ZSzoPT55UE/Payload/ConsumeWS.app failed with error 1. Output: /var/folders/6w/ycncqpg12mj_l56xbqgly6_80000gn/T/ZSzoPT55UE/Payload/ConsumeWS.app: replacing existing signature
[03:44:00 PM] Program /usr/bin/codesign returned 1 : [/var/folders/6w/ycncqpg12mj_l56xbqgly6_80000gn/T/ZSzoPT55UE/Payload/ConsumeWS.app: replacing existing signature
[03:44:00 PM] Command-line execution failed (Return code: 1)
[03:44:00 PM] Deployment cancelled.
[03:44:00 PM] ----  Deployment incomplete  ----.
[03:44:00 PM] Failed to package the XCode application.
[03:44:00 PM] Failed to build the iOS application bundle.
[03:44:00 PM] Deployment failed due to one or more errors returned by '/usr/bin/xcrun'.  The following is a summary of the returned error(s):
Command-line execution failed (Return code: 1)
error: /usr/bin/codesign --force --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements,resource-rules --sign iPhone Developer: Rakesh Raman (G445TJT9SV) --resource-rules=/var/folders/6w/ycncqpg12mj_l56xbqgly6_80000gn/T/ZSzoPT55UE/Payload/ConsumeWS.app/ResourceRules.plist /var/folders/6w/ycncqpg12mj_l56xbqgly6_80000gn/T/ZSzoPT55UE/Payload/ConsumeWS.app failed with error 1. Output: /var/folders/6w/ycncqpg12mj_l56xbqgly6_80000gn/T/ZSzoPT55UE/Payload/ConsumeWS.app: replacing existing signature
Program /usr/bin/codesign returned 1 : [/var/folders/6w/ycncqpg12mj_l56xbqgly6_80000gn/T/ZSzoPT55UE/Payload/ConsumeWS.app: replacing existing signature
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of JDeveloper are you using?
You need to be using 11.1.2.4.

Comment: Hi @Shay Shmeltzer, i am using latest version of JDeveloper then it giving me same error. For deploying in device, i am using this url reference: http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/11gdemos/adfmobiledeployios.html

Comment: Hi @Shay Shmeltzer, I am using version 11.1.2.4 then it giving me same error. Can you please help out on this issue?